# What's the latest version of Boost compatible with VC++6?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, visual-c++-6

What is the latest version of the Boost library that is compatible with Microsoft Visual C++ 6?  And can you provide a link to download it directly?

The Downloads link at http://www.boost.org only gives a download for version 1.36.0, and the documentation for that version lists Visual C++ 7.1 as the lowest version of Microsoft compiler tested.  Do they purge out downloads for older versions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Boost [1.34.1](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_34_1) has been tested with vc6.  The old versions are still available.

Comment: Unfortunately even with this boost version Visual C++ 6 seems to have problems (e.g. the algorithm/string stuff doesn't compile...)

Answer (score 11):

You can get all older versions from [the boost download page on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=7586&package_id=8041).

The compilers used for regression tests are probably buried somewhere on the boost.org website.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't accept two answers - this was very helpful indeed. Thanks.

Comment: Yep. +1, i was able to find the download

Answer (score 5):

It's worth noting that Boost doesn't actively *not* support VC6 either. Most of the boost libs probably still work with VC6 (they haven't stripped out the VC6 compatibility code, as far as I know)

So you could just try 1.36.1 and see how far you get.

Comment: what I get now (1.58) is  #error :  "Compiler not supported or configured - please reconfigure"

Comment: Well, my answer is 7 years old after all. :) I hope for your sake you'll be able to upgrade to a decent compiler soon. :)

Comment: Because of changes in Boost, I found I needed to drop back to Boost 1.3x to get the application to compile anyway.