# how can I get a std::set of keys to a std::map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, set

I was writing an algorithm this morning and I ran into a curious situation.  I have two `std::map`s.  I want to perform a set intersection on the sets of the keys of each (to find which keys are common to both maps).  At some point in the future, I think it's likely I'll also want to perform set subtraction here as well.  Luckily, the STL includes functions for both of those operations.  The problem is, I can't seem to get a `std::set` of the keys out of a `std::map`.  Is there any way to do this?  I'm looking for something that would be this simple, like it is in Java:

```
std::set<Foo> keys = myMap.getKeySet();
```

My understanding is that I can't use the `std::set_intersection()` function directly on iterators into the maps because the maps expose `std::pair` objects instead of just keys.  Also, I don't think the map guarantees order.  I'm also interested in performing this same operation on a pair of `std::multimap`s, if that makes any difference.

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention initially that due to the age of the compiler I'm forced to use (MSVC++ 6), most of the nifty template tricks that are available in boost can not be used.

Comment: Don't be so quick to give up on MSVC++ 6 - see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252492/whats-the-latest-version-of-boost-compatible-with-vc6

Comment: Map does keep keys in order

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the versatile boost::transform_iterator to return an iterator that returns only the keys (and not the values). See [How to retrieve all keys (or values) from a std::map and put them into a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110157/how-to-retrieve-all-keys-or-values-from-a-stdmap/110228#110228)

Comment: this seems like a perfect solution, but I doubt it will compile for me... see my edit to the question.

Answer (score 24):

What you basically want is a copy, as std::map doesn't keep the keys in a std::set. std::copy assumes that the value types are compatible, which isn't the case here. The std::map::value_type is a std::pair. You want to copy only the first part of the pair, which means you need a std::transform. Now, since you will be using an insert_iterator on the set, order doesn't matter. The std::set will sort on insertion, even though the map was already sorted.

[edit] Code might be easier. Top of my head, not compiled.

```
std::transform(MyMap.begin(), MyMap.end(),
    std::inserter(MySet, MySet.end()),
    boost::bind(&std::pair<Key,Value>::first, _1));
```

If you've got SGI's select1st, you don't need the boost::bind.

[edit]
Updated for C++14

```
std::transform(MyMap.begin(), MyMap.end(),
    std::inserter(MySet, MySet.end()),
    [](auto pair){ return pair.first; });
```

Comment: I can't quite follow what you're saying, but it seems to me that this is likely the "right" solution.  It's also a lot more complex (sounding) than rlbond's answer (which is what I'm already doing).  Can you provide example code?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of a version of inserter() taking only one argument. And using the two-arguments version would be a good thing as it uses the set's "insert with hint" operation, taking advantage of the fact that map's elements are sorted. "std::inserter(MySet, MySet.end())".

Comment: Yup, back_inserter is the one-arg one. Fixed.

Answer (score 12):

Map *does* guarantee order; that's why it's called a sorted associative container. You can use set_intersection with a custom comparator function, the second variant listed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

So, something like

```
bool your_less(const your_map::value_type &v1, const your_map::value_type &v2)
{ return v1.first < v2.first; }

set_intersection(m1.begin(), m1.end(), m2.begin(), m2.end(), your_output_it, your_less);
```

should do the trick. (It is also possible to use boost::lambda and bind to avoid writing a temporary function.)

The default operator< over pairs compares both components.  Since you need equivalence only over the first part of the pair (the map key), you need to define your own comparison operator that provides such relation (which is what the function above does).

Comment: For anyone else trying this, I don't believe it works.  I attempted this and found I was falling afoul of `set_intersection`'s assignment operation, `*_Dest++ = *_First1++;`. The key is const in the map's pair, so the assignment fails (with a horrid incomprehensible template error).

Answer (score 11):

In practice,

```
yourmap::const_iterator mi;
set<key_type> k;
for (mi = yourmap.begin(); mi != yourmap.end(); ++mi)
  k.insert(mi->first);
return k;
```

Answer (score 6):

The best non-SGI, non-boost STL algorithm-friendly solution is to extend map::iterator like so:

```
template<typename map_type>
class key_iterator : public map_type::iterator
{
public:
    typedef typename map_type::iterator map_iterator;
    typedef typename map_iterator::value_type::first_type key_type;

    key_iterator(const map_iterator& other) : map_type::iterator(other) {} ;

    key_type& operator *()
    {
        return map_type::iterator::operator*().first;
    }
};

// helpers to create iterators easier:
template<typename map_type>
key_iterator<map_type> key_begin(map_type& m)
{
    return key_iterator<map_type>(m.begin());
}
template<typename map_type>
key_iterator<map_type> key_end(map_type& m)
{
    return key_iterator<map_type>(m.end());
}
```

and then use them like so:

```
        map<string,int> test;
        test["one"] = 1;
        test["two"] = 2;

        set<string> keys;

//      // method one
//      key_iterator<map<string,int> > kb(test.begin());
//      key_iterator<map<string,int> > ke(test.end());
//      keys.insert(kb, ke);

//      // method two
//      keys.insert(
//           key_iterator<map<string,int> >(test.begin()),
//           key_iterator<map<string,int> >(test.end()));

        // method three (with helpers)
        keys.insert(key_begin(test), key_end(test));
```

Comment: This is genius. Since I dont actually just want a set but even iterators to access it. With this solution i have everything i want  with no additional dependencies :)

Answer (score 3):

You can just iterate through and add each key to a set. Sets and maps are both ordered, unordered variants are not.

Comment: this is essentially what I'm already doing.  I thought there might be some better way, where "better" means either "more standard" or "better performing".

Answer (score 2):

I found good link for your question [here](http://bytes.com/groups/cpp/759728-initialize-std-set-keys-std-map)

and have some code for your problem:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <map>
    #include <set>
    #include <iterator>

    typedef std::map<std::string, int> MyMap;

    // also known as select1st in SGI STL implementation
    template<typename T_PAIR>
    struct GetKey: public std::unary_function<T_PAIR, typename T_PAIR::first_type>
    {
        const typename T_PAIR::first_type& operator()(const T_PAIR& item) const
        {
            return item.first;
        }
    };

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        MyMap m1,m2;

        m1["a"] = 1;
        m1["b"] = 2;
        m2["c"] = 3;
        m2["b"] = 3;

        std::set<std::string> s;
        std::transform(m1.begin(), m1.end(), std::inserter(s, s.begin()), GetKey<MyMap::value_type>());
        std::transform(m2.begin(), m2.end(), std::inserter(s, s.begin()), GetKey<MyMap::value_type>());
        std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, if you could not use SGI select1st or boost, then you have to code it yourself. For me it’s a good exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps create an iterator for a map which only yields the keys using boost::adapters::map_key, see example in the [boost::adapters::map_key documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_keys.html). This appears to have been introduced in Boost 1.43, and is supposed to be C++ 2003 compatible, but I don't know about VC++ 6 specifically, which is from the C++ 98 era.

Comment: Is the map_key adapter available in a version of Boost that works with VC6? If not, can you *edit* the question to include this disclaimer? If so, can you link to older documentation from, say, the 1.34 era?

Comment: @chwarr - thanks for bringing this constraint to my attention. Looks like this is from Boost 1.43, as the earliest revision of the Boost docs that appears to have it is http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_keys.html .

Answer (score 1):

Building up from the answer from zvrba and the comment from dianot:

Just make the receiving collection be a vector of pairs instead of a map, and the problem pointed by dianot is over. So, using zvrba example:

```
std::vector<std::pair<keytype, valtype>> v;

set_intersection(m1.begin(), m1.end(), m2.begin(), m2.end(),
std::back_inserter(v), []( std::pair<keytype, valtype> const & a,
std::pair<keytype, valtype> const & b){return a.first < b.first;});
```

So without constructing intermediate copies or sets we can get efficiently the intersection of two maps. This construction compiles with gcc5.3.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by using function templates

```
template <class T, class U>
set<T> getSetFromKeys(map<T,U> mapWithKeys){

  set<T> outputSet;

  for (pair<const T, U> keyValuePair : mapWithKeys) {
    outputSet.insert(keyValuePair.first);
  }

  return outputSet; 
}
```

In this way I had a generic way of extracting keys from maps in my application.

Answer (score 0):

As MSalters says you might want to just create a set of the keys. This may be good enough for a small map.

A quick way to do this is:

```
std::set<Foo> keys;
for (auto &iter : myMap)
{
   keys.insert(iter.first);
}
```