# How to write a const_iterator in VC++6?

Tags: c++

I have implemented my own container class and need to implement a const_iterator for it. What is the easiest way to go about implementing `const_iterator begin()` `const_iterator end()` and `const_iterator::operator++` for my own container class?

Please provide examples. Thanks!

Comment: Just upgrade. Really, sticking with VC++6  is no longer sane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems boost library has a compatible version to be used with VC6 according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252492/whats-the-latest-version-of-boost-compatible-with-vc6). In that case you can use either `boost::iterator_facade` or `boost::iterator_adaptor` to easily write a `const_iterator` class. If you can't use boost, then the only option I see is to write a class derived from `std::iterator` and write all the required operator overloads.