# What is the perl format and best regular expression library that compile in MS VC++6.0?

Tags: regex, boost, visual-c++-6

I wrote a program in c++ in VC++2008 with boost library for regular expression. But my code must be compiled in vc++6.0 compiler. vc++6 has compile error when using regular expression(I'm not actually sure but I can't compile boostRegex in vc++6). 
So, for changing my library from boost, what is your opinion to me(one that is more similar to boost regex is better, for decreasing cost of converting. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular Expression Library component int [this site](http://www.tropicsoft.com/Components/RegularExpression/);

Answer (score 2):

Boost 1.34.1 is supposedly the [last version which supports VC6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252492/whats-the-latest-version-of-boost-compatible-with-vc6), and [includes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/) the regex lib.  Likely it'd be be easier to revert to that version than switch to a completely different library.