# making latest boost working with Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: visual-c++, boost, visual-c++-6

i want to make boost library working with Visual C++ 6.0, but it fail at include state with various errors:

```
e:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\boost\config\suffix.hpp(603) : error C2039: 'typeinfo' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
e:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\boost\config\suffix.hpp(603) : error C2873: 'typeinfo' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
e:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp(192) : error C2954: template definitions cannot nest
e:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp(192) : error C2951: template declarations are only permitted at global or namespace scope
e:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp(192) : error C2226: syntax error : unexpected type 'IndexType'
e:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp(193) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '>' before ';'
e:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp(193) : error C2059: syntax error : '<end Parse>'
e:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp(205) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
e:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp(205) : error C2059: syntax error : '<'
e:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp(207) : error C2955: 'iset_index' : use of class template requires template argument list
        e:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vc98\include\boost\interprocess\interprocess_fwd.hpp(180) : see declaration of 'iset_index'
```

Comment: I don't know this for certain, but given Boost's heavy reliance on templates, and Visual C++ 6.0's relatively poor support for the C++ standard and for templates (by modern standards) I'd be surprised if you're ever going to get this to work. 

Also, what version of Boost are you using? An older version might be better, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252492/whats-the-latest-version-of-boost-compatible-with-vc6

Comment: Are these errors occurring while building the Boost binaries, or while compiling a program that uses Boost?

Comment: Thanks, this errors is when i compile program using boost and yes i see it fails to compile complex template structures.

Comment: why not use Use visual studio 2010 express in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using 1.34.1

Comment: Thanks, it does not have interprocess library =(